# creating content types with Out-of-Box vs Server Object models

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-enterprise

Are there any advantages in creating content type using out of box vs visual studios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "out of the box" you mean creating them in the User Interface.

**Advantages of Visual Studio**

- Easy way to deploy identical content types across multiple farms
- Internal Content Type ID is the same for every deployment
- Direct control over every property/value used in creation of the
  content type

**Disadvantages of Visual Studio**

- Process is a bit more complex
- Requires a developer to make the change
- Requires a server admin to deploy the change

**Advantages of the User Interface**

- No deployment required so it does not require a server admin
- Changes can be made easily and quickly

**Disadvantage of User Interface**

- A typo made in a name when creating the type basically breaks the
  type as it creates a field with the wrong internal name and that
  cannot be changed from the UI
- Content type and all changes must be done manually and identically in
  all environments
- Unable to specifically set many internal key fields (i.e.
  ContentTypeID)